# Difference between 顾客, 客, 客户 and 客人

Tags: vocabulary, difference

As in the title what is the difference in word usage/meaning between the following fours words:

1. **客**
2. **顾客**
3. **客户**
4. **客人**

?

Comment: answer found in dictionaries, 客 is a bound morpheme (see dictionaries for compounds, suffix as in 酒客,刺客,政客 ) 顾客 customer; client; shopper，客户 client; customer；buyer；（trading) partner,客人 guest,visitor, also see previous question https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16776/what-is-the-difference-between-%e9%a1%be%e5%ae%a2-and-%e5%ae%a2%e6%88%b7 for difference between 顾客 and  客户

Answer (score 1, accepted):

客, guest, visitor. For a shop, it is customer.

顧客, customer. (顧, look back -> visit and revisit.)

客户, customer account, a customer with account. (户, the front door -> household -> account). Some ignore the concept of account.

客人, 人客. guest / visitor (of human).

Answer (score 0):

顾客 and 客户 are customer(commercial ).
客人 means guest.
客 always means being guest/objective,which is contrast to  the owner/subjective.

Answer (score -1):

1. 客 is short for 客人 mostly, sometimes short for customer.
2. 客人: guest, visitor
3. 顾客: customer
4. 客户: client